# My Laptop Won't Boot When There's a Hard Drive plugged in through SATA

Tags: boot

I have an HP Pavilion dv6-1235et (everything including BIOS is up-to-date) and during an everyday use, it suddenly freezed. i waited for a couple of minutes; however, nothing happened so i forced the laptop to turn off. Then I pressed the power button in order to power it on, I saw the HP logo and stuff, but instead of Windows 10 logo, an error screen appeared, saying "Boot Device Not Found", "Please install an operating system on your hard disk.", and "Hard Disk (3F0)".

Facts to consider:

- This BIOS (InsydeH2O F.44 Rev3.5) does have neither of the options Legacy Boot nor Secure Boot as it can already be seen from the images in the links below.
- Boot priority is in the correct order according to the requirements of this case.
- When a SATA drive is connected, BIOS shows it with the name "Notebook Hard Drive".
- The pc passes all the built-in tests except "Primary Hard Disk Self Test" (Full Test) and says Hard Disk 1 Full (305)
- When a SATA drive is plugged in, no matter what bootable device is connected, a black screen with a winking horizontal line appears, and that is it.
- The SATA drive contains important data that must be recovered and has Windows 10 installed.
- Three different HDDs have been tested, so the problem is not with the SATA drive.
- If the SATA drive is removed but a bootable device is connected, the PC boots normally.
- When the SATA drive (the one that contains important data) is externally connected to another Windows running PC, the PC says that the Hard Drive must be formatted to be opened. In this way, I also checked the Hard Drive with Disk Manager and I saw four different partitions in the Drive: if I remember correctly; there is one for System (500MB), one for Recovery (822mb) and two for personal use (C: and D:). Additionally, in the properties section for these partitions, it says RAW (now I tried the chkdsk command when the HDD was externally connected, it said NTFS, good thing to know)
- After removing the SATA drive, I booted it to Linux Mint, then plugged in the Hard Drive. Linux Mint says that it cannot mount the Hard Drive and suggested that I resume the Windows 10 and turn it off properly. It made me think that the Hard Drive controller supports hot swapping.
  On the other hand, when I plug out the Hard Drive, boot the pc using Windows 10 DVD, then plug the SATA Drive back in, Windows does not detect any SATA Drive connected (I checked it with command-line, using diskpart, and the repair tools in the DVD)

The problem is that the pc does not boot anything when there is a Hard Drive plugged in through SATA.

BIOS images:

- http://hizliresim.com/6Nr8jE
- http://hizliresim.com/WDgEjP
- http://hizliresim.com/3zvPk5
- http://hizliresim.com/RD1BjZ

Test Failed:

- https://prnt.sc/k5jsn7

**UPDATE**

I plugged the Hard Drive that has important data externally into the faulty PC after booting to Win 10 Recovery DVD's Command Line and ran the chkdsk *:/f command for the personal partitions. The result is worth checking and can be found in the links below.

- http://prntscr.com/k5otht
- http://prntscr.com/k5otot
- http://prntscr.com/k5ottr

**UPDATE 2**

It is proved that the aforementioned Hard Drive is faulty due to the following evidence: when the Hard Drive is plugged in to a computer, the pc slows down dramatically; and the error that is encountered while formatting the Hard Drive suggests that the hardware is not working properly. 
Even though the HDD is faulty, critical data in the HDD is secured with GParted.

However, whatever it is that causes the laptop not to boot properly when there is a Hard Drive connected through SATA remains unknown, and there is still data in the faulty HDD that was not purged even after the several formatting attempts made utilizing different software on different operating systems. Hence, this thread is still active, awaiting your advices.

**VERY SIGNIFICANT UPDATE**

I tried to boot the laptop when another SATA drive was plugged in internally and it turns out that the other three HDDs are all faulty, since this time PC booted to Linux without a single problem. From now on, I will be attempting to repair the other three Hard Drives and most likely am going to ask more questions on this website related to the Hard Drives.
Thanks to those who endured my messy way of solving the problem and did not hesitate to give any advice they could think of on account of solving the problem.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "does not boot"? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error? Is there data on the SATA drive and is it supposed to be bootable? Can you boot to another medium while the SATA drive is in the computer? Have you updated BIOS firmware and checked settings?

Comment: All the BIOS settings are checked, and BIOS is up-to-date (an old bios for an 8 year old computer.) I cannot boot to anything while the SATA drive is plugged in. I was using the SATA drive before I encountered this problem, so it must have Windows 10 installed. When I turn the laptop on, while the SATA drive is in the computer, all I see is a black screen.

Comment: @lewegeu123 so with the SATA drive pluged in it's not possible to get into the BIOS? If the screen stays blank, is there something else happening after you press the power on?

Comment: I see the HP logo and can get into BIOS etc. However, when it starts booting to an operating system or a program, nothing really happens than me staring at a black screen for hours.

Comment: Have you tried multiple drives? What happens when you attempt to boot to USB while the SATA drive is connected? I'm assuming your HDD just isn't set up to boot on this computer at this time, either due to nothing being installed on it, or the things installed on it not being configured properly.

Comment: Also, rather than adding information in comments, which means someone has to read the original post AND all the comments to grasp what has been discussed, please use the EDIT button to add requested and relevant information to the original question, so that the question becomes more accurate and complete and good answers can be derived from just the question.

Comment: When the SATA drive is inside the pc, no matter what bootable device is plugged in, I face a black screen.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, this is really the first question I asked on this website, so it'll take time for me to get used to the format. I'll revise the question and put together all the information I provided in the original question. Thank you.

Comment: I can not view the images, is it just me? @lewegeu123 if you can please check if the drive gets recognized by the BIOS. Also if possible please check if works with a different machine, e.g. as external HD connected through USB. You can't please check if the HD controller supports hot swapping the SATA drive. If it does, boot an OS first, then plug in the drive see if that works. These are all "into the blind" suggestions but might give potential clues. For specific trouble shooting you still didn't provide enough detailed information!

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions and PCs detect the drive when it is externally connected. Though, naturally, I cannot open it.

Comment: @lewegeu123 you need to describe it in more detail. What do you mean by "opening" it? Why did it not work? What about my other suggestion, what were the results?

Comment: @music2myear As you instructed, all the information are now also in the original question.

Comment: @Albin I answered this question of yours in the original question.

Comment: @lewegeu123 "Three different HDDs have been tested, so the problem is not with the SATA drive." - what do you mean? what was the test? what was the result of the test? From the result how do you get to the conclusion that the "problem is not with the SATA drive"? Or do you mean "SATA controller"?

Comment: I tried booting it to Linux when a SATA drive was plugged in internally, and I did this three times with three different Hard Drives. In none of the attempts it managed to boot to Linux Mint.

Comment: @lewegeu123 so you put three other SATA drives into the laptop and the same problem occurred? Did you preform a drive test on them? did it come up with the same error?

Comment: @lewegeu123 I updated my answer

Comment: "Hard Disk (3F0)" Your hard drive has failed, replace it.....https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01443463

Comment: @Moab Replacing the Hard Drive does not solve the problem.

Comment: Until you run the full hardware diagnostics you may not know what the issue is.

Comment: Can it be possible that Linux suggesting I should properly turn off Windows and then try mounting it is a sign of Windows is not shut down properly and left its trace in the laptop? I know it sounds like a fantasy but I feel helpless.

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT:** 
**If you want to recover data you should stop using the HD altogether. The error code means the Full test could not be completed (if I'm not mistaken)! If it is possible, clone the content of the drive to a different hard drive, and keep the original hard drive safe. Although this is not mandatory, it will be your safest option. If you continue to work on the faulty drive there is always the risk of losing the data permanently. Keep in mind: the drive could also fail completely (in this case assume the test result is correct and the drive is actually faulty).**

After you cloned the hard drive, you need to decide, do you just want the data to be recovered to a new drive (then I would suggest to start a new question), or do you want to be able to bootup your system again.

The hard disc is failing and most likely already some data corruption occurred. If the OS says it needs to be formatted if the drive is connected externally it can not find any partitions or it can not find any format on those partitions. You should check what it is.

For now I assume it can not find any partitions, which means the partition table is corrupted. Restoring the partition table (including the flag that specifies which partition to boot from) might already solve the problem of making the data accessible and the drive bootable again. But if there is more data corruption – for example, the boot sector itself is corrupted – it might be more complicated.

If you want to find out more about your error, you need to find out what exactly failed – for example, by using a more detailed test program or changing the settings on the internal testing program (if possible).

On the slim chance the drive is ok and the test result is caused by something else, we might need a different approach altogether. Please see my last comments (questions) in your question.

---

For your "original question", how to boot the computer with the (faulty) HD already inside, I still think it's a matter of setting up the BIOS. The laptop should not try to access a disc drive if it's not supposed to be used for booting up, but I'm not 100 percent sure. Anyway I leave the information in case you want to try it in the future...

During BIOS-bootup the computer makes more or less conclusive checks on the hardware, so if the BIOS detects the HD correctly (which you did not check yet) and stops the OS-Boot-Process when the drive is inserted it's most likely that it tries to boot from the HD but is unable to (for whatever reasons).

Most likely you need to change your BIOS boot setting. Make sure that the PC boots from CD first (or whatever device you use to install Windows from) before it tries to boot from HD. If it's the other way around the PC tries to boot from HD and stops since it can not "find" a proper OS (loosely speaking).

Another possibility but very unlikely is that there is something wrong with your harddrive or with the hard drive connection, the controller or a setting in regards to harddrive/harddrive controller. In this case the system might detect a problem and stop the boot process. Without further information we can only speculate.

If you set up your system NOT to boot from HD correctly (but the evidence so far suggests otherwise), I would check the following first:

- is the HD working correctly? (most likely no but still uncertain)
- is the SATA-Controller working correctly? (most likely yes but still uncertain)
- is the connection is working correctly e.g., problems with the plug? (most likely yes but still uncertain)

In the comments for your question you have several suggestion on how to check it further.

Comment: Agreed, first thing to try is to change the boot order in BIOS.  If that doesn't work, rule out problems with the hard drive itself... plug it into another setup and see if it works.  It may be useful to format the hard drive there.  For instance, you could plug it into a desktop PC or a USB external SATA connector.  It's possible (but unlikely) that the laptop does not support the particular model of hard drive; I've seen that happen once.  It may be useful to get another hard drive and try it in the laptop.

Comment: Oh, there are so many things I tried. I assure you that boot priority is not the problem, and it is already adjusted for this case. I already tried installing 3 different HDDs but still I cannot get this problem fixed. I suppose that there is something wrong with something related to internal hard drive.

Comment: @lewegeu123 in this case you should first elaborate on music2myear's question, see his comment to your question. Did you try to remove the hard disk as a boot device? You should also elaborate on what you tried already, otherwise there are too many possible solutions. Maybe you could also send a screenshot of you BIOS settings (at least the screen with the boot devices / priorites)

Comment: @Albin Currently, the SATA drive is removed and it can boot to Linux Mint through a USB stick. By the way, I already answered his questions. Now, let me just take some photos of BIOS.

Comment: @lewegeu123 you are right, with this info, it's more likely to be s.th. else. I thing you need to provide more info first.

Comment: Requested images are added.

Comment: @Albin More details are added to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you're dealing with an older computer (DV6 laptop) and you have a failed/failing hard drive. Laptops often have fewer options in their BIOS and I would guess the system is trying to boot from the HDD no matter what your settings are.

SATA is hot-swap. It's just a feature. Some software may not like hot-swapping, but most modern OSes (including Linux) handle it just fine.

Let's just **stop trying to power the computer with the faulty HDD connected**. There is no reason to try this because you've already proved it won't work. We'll just proceed to the next thing you tried: powering the computer on and booting to a different medium and then connecting the drive because both Windows and Linux are able to see the drive at that point.

The remaining issue is **data recovery**. The OS doesn't need to format or scan or do anything else to the drive in order for data recovery to work. You just need to select the appropriate or preferred data recovery utility and tell it to work on that faulty drive. There are several questions here on SuperUser about Data Recovery. I suggest you start here and narrow the search to find solutions appropriate for your needs: https://superuser.com/search?q=data+recovery

**Re-reading the question, again:** There are likely two issues: The drive is faulty, and the laptop drive controller (or something else inside the laptop pertinent to the drive connection). If the laptop won't boot with ANY HDD in it, than the issue is not *just* with the disks (as you've already noted), but with the computer as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After I recover the data, I will still need to fix the pc since the problem is not with the hard drive. Ergo, I still need some help.

Comment: @lewegeu123 no, the problem IS most likely with the hard drive. There might be an issue with the controller or the connection, but that is rather unlikely.

Comment: @music2myear I thing you are jumping to conclusions here. I would wait what he says, maybe he want's his old system to boot again and not only to recover the data. Also there is still the slim chance the drive is not faulty but the data corruption is caused by s.th. else (for example a faulty controller that results in a faulty drive test as well)

Comment: He's already stated that the HDD reports errors in a test, and that both Windows and Linux report various issues with the disk as well. Even after recovery, the drive should not be trusted. Drives are cheap and compatibility should not be an issue, even with an older system. This drive should be recovered from, and then not used in any situation requiring reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your laptop model number, it looks like it is an old model. That can cause a lot of problems in this case.

If it's just a black screen, there are two cases here:

1. The hard disk is slow, and/or Windows / BIOS couldn't detect the hard disk.
2. The hard disk is dead, but your PC is taking it as it's still working.

Because, if the hard disk is empty/dead and BIOS recognized it, BIOS would respond "INSERT BOOT DEVICE" or something like that.

***I'll recommend if Installing Windows 7 / 8 works, you should just upgrade it from there, instead of installing Windows 10 directly.***

But let's get down to the basics here.

Before starting, You should check your laptop hard disk power rating, because it may be giving less power to the hard disk, that it function incorrectly / slower.

First if you wouldn't mind, change the BIOS's SATA controller from AHCI to IDE, since this WILL give backwards compatibility for your hardware. You can change this later, this won't be a problem "in most cases". (Unless after installing OS you want to revert to AHCI, but this can be fixed by going to safe mode, ***you can look this up later***).

Then you should turn off some settings regarding the hard drive, like: Intel Rapid Start Technology (Although I think this has nothing to do except for SSDs), Turbo Mode: OFF, etc.

Change the priority:

1. 1st should be Bootable device,
2. 2nd should be DVD/CD drive
3. 3rd SHOULD be your Hard Disk.
4. else, go to the bottom.

If you are using USB, remove any, and I mean ANY CD/DVD that is in your CD/DVD Drive. The same other way, if you're using CD/DVD.

Next thing is, you should make sure your RAM and processor are working correctly (memory tools and such), and then try again. This should work in the regular way. If not, comment down below.

Comment: I think I misguided you guys. The corrected and detailed information are now in the original question.

Comment: Hey! Since I don't have the privilege to comment just yet, I wanted to tell you that if you could make Two OS's-es on that hard drive, and use EasyBCD on the second OS? You should look up on that app, but I was thinking, since you clone the HDD, the BIOS couldn't understand where is the OS, so this is where the App is used, to guide the BIOS to your main OS. @lewegeu123

Comment: When I try to install an OS on the HDD, I encounter multifarious errors.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the following steps:
1.go to bios and check if there hard disk is connected 
2.If hard disc is connected then try to repair your operating system either from 
  recovery or last known good configuration.
3.change your sata cable and try.
4.if you have changed anything in bios then setup default setting.
5.clean your hard disc port and try

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as it can be seen from the last update in the question, I determined that the Sata Drive is faulty.